# Applications and Volume level bug/glitch

Tags: 13.04, sound, games, volume-control

I have an HP dv4 laptop running Ubuntu 13.04, that has a weird bug when I play some games on it. So when I go into the game, the volume will just go crazy, going up and down, and does not stop. I'm not sure what else to say, but I'm more than happy to provide anything helpful..

Comment: For which game(s) does this occur? You need to be more specific. Please add this information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem. But able to get work arround with this command.

```
sudo rm /dev/input/js0
```

Some games detect keyboard as joystick. So I removed it. But don't know whether it causes any problem or not. Right now I don't have any though.

Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar problem, but not with games. Just randomly the volume starts to increase and just keep going, past the point of being maxed out. I always just assumed it was hardware related. It's happened to me since 11.04